# Angular 2 custom composite control

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create a custom composite control for Angular 2. My requirements are I need to create a generic file-picker control that allows users to select a file **either** using a html5 input[type=file] **or** by inputing a url to a file.

I've decided to create generic form controls that implement the ControlValueAccessor interface for a both the sub-controls, as they are going to be used elsewhere individually.

I'm trying to wrap them both inside a *file-picker-local-or-remote* (for lack of a better word) control. This outer control should be responsible for emitting the contents of the file chosen, without caring how the file was picked.

Propagating the value all the way to the consuming form is easy. Every time the subcontrols propagates a value to the intermediary control, the intermediary control relays it further up the chain to the consumer, using the registerChange callback.

However, I'm having trouble propagating validation errors that might occur in the subcontrols. I need to propagate the errors all the way to the consuming form so that they may be localised.

E.g. If a user enters an invalid url in the remote-file-picker subcontrol, that subcontrol's validation function fires with the correct error. This error is given to the intermediary control. How can I propagate this invalid-url error all the way to the consuming form?

More broadly, is there specific guidance about how to create composite controls in Angular 2? I can't find any examples of custom controls that wrap other custom controls, so I'm not really sure I'm doing it correctly.

Put differently, given:

Form:

```
outerForm = new FormGroup({
    file: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
});

<form [formGroup]="outerForm">
    <File-Picker-Local-Or-Remote formControlName="file"></File-Picker-Local-Or-Remote>
    <span class="error">******???******</span>
</form>
```

File-Picker-Local-Or-Remote

```
innerForm = new FormGroup({
    local: new FormControl(),
    remote: new FormControl(null, Validators.pattern('http://...'))
});

<input type="file" formControlName="local" />
<input type="text" formControlName="remote" />
```

When the remote subcontrol fails validation, it gives its error codes to the innerForm. How do I propagate those error messages to the outer form, so that I can replace ******???****** with the appropriate validation message?

Edit: I should note that there are quite a fews ways for me to hack a solution or bypass this problem, including building my own solution using event emitters, not having a composite control in the first place, etc.

What I'm actually interested in is the *Angular 2 way* of creating reusable and extensible form controls that consumers can interact with just like any other form control, and can be further built upon by other developers to create even more high-level controls.

Comment: You can make use of event emitter in case the inner form throws errors and catch it in the parent form

Comment: I've clarified my question in response to your comment. There are countless ad-hoc solutions to this, as with most programming problems. What I'd like to know is the Angular 2 way of creating reusable and extensible form controls. E.g. In the future, I may want to wrap <File-Picker-Local-Or-Remote> into a brand new control called <File-Picker-Local-Or-Remote-Or-Create-New> that also includes a rich-text area. I shouldn't have to modify an existing, working form control to provide a different interface to other parent controls. Or should I?

Comment: I guess you are talking about Custom Form Controls ?

Comment: If you are Please look at this link https://medium.com/@tarik.nzl/angular-2-custom-form-control-with-validation-json-input-2b4cf9bc2d73#.nuafuagqf.
I am not that Expert but hope this might help you

Comment: Yep, all controls I mentioned above are custom controls that implement ControlValueAccessor. The intermediary control basically listens for changes to subcontrols and propagates changes in them to the consuming form. However, it's not clear to me out to propagate **errors** to the consuming form. That's what I need to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A colleague and I figured this out a while ago but here is the solution for anyone else stumbling across this.

The key is to implement both ControlValueAccessor and Validator interfaces in the composite component.

E.g.

Custom **date** control, implements ControlValueAccessor

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: CustomDateControl),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class CustomDateControl implements ControlValueAccessor {
  // implement ControlValueAccessor
}
```

Custom **time** control, implements ControlValueAccessor

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: CustomTimeControl),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class CustomTimeControl implements ControlValueAccessor {
  // implement ControlValueAccessor
}
```

Custom composite control **dateTime**, implements both ControlValueAccessor **and** Validator

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
    useExisting: CustomDateTimeControl,
    multi: true
  }, {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: CustomDateTimeControl,
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class CustomDateTimeControl implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
  private propagateChange = function (change) { };
  private propagateTouched = function () { };

  // Inner controls (you can also use an internal FormGroup for this)
  public date = new FormControl();
  public time = new FormControl();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.date.valueChanges
      .subscribe(value => {
        this.propagateChange(value + ' ' + this.time.value);
        this.propagateTouched();
      }

    this.time.valueChanges
      .subscribe(value => {
        this.propagateChange(this.date.value + ' ' + value);
        this.propagateTouched();
      }
    }

  writeValue(value) {
    // Need to update the inner controls, but don't use setValue / patchValue,
    // as that will trigger valueChanges in the above subscriptions,
    // incorrectly calling touched
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.propagateTouched = fn;
  }

  validate(control) {
    // Custom logic to validate the parent control. In this case,
    // we may choose to union all childrens' errors.

    let errors = Object.assign(this.localControl.errors || {}, this.remoteControl.errors || {});
    return Object.keys(errors).length ? errors : null;
  }
}
```

To my answer my own initial question, a good way to bubble errors up a chain of composite controls is to implement Validator in those composite controls, and have their validate function return some combination of the child controls' errors.

I hope this is useful for others.

Comment: do you have a working stackblitz link or any demo links with the code for this? That will be really helpful. thank you.